# Why does this program fail to compile when the error is unreachable?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I'm making a class for variable bit size pixel color values. Anyways, I got it working but there is something odd:

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename my_type>
struct c {
    my_type x;

    c() {}
    c(my_type x) { this->x = x; }

    template<typename target_type>
    c<target_type> convert() {
        if (std::is_same<my_type, target_type>::value) {
            return *this; //<- doesn't work
            return *reinterpret_cast<c<target_type>*>(this); //<- does work
        }

        int target_size = sizeof(((c<target_type>*)0)->x);
        int my_size = sizeof(x);

        if (my_size < target_size) {
            return c<target_type>(x << (target_size - my_size) * 8);
        }

        my_type rounder = ((x >> (my_size - target_size) * 8 - 1) & 9) > 4;
        return c<target_type>((x >> (my_size - target_size) * 8) + rounder);    
    }

};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

on the line I marked, I should be able to return just *this but if I do that and try to compile with the following test:

```
c<uint8_t> a;
c<uint32_t> b(2147483647);
a = b.convert<uint8_t>();
```

then I get the error

```
cannot convert from c<uint32_t> to c<uint8_t>
```

which makes no sense because it isn't supposed to convert anything if its the same type which is not the case with `uint32_t` to `uint8_t`

This is on MSVC, does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: `cannot convert from c<uint32_t> to c<uint8_t>` Well, you can't, what's actualy unclear?

Comment: Do you really have two returns back-to-back in your `if` statement or is that a poor-man's comment?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that scenario can never happen

Comment: Highly suggest editing title to be expressive.

Comment: @PasserBy I tried to edit it to be a bit more clear... open to other edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, when you do:

```
if (std::is_same<my_type, target_type>::value) {
    return *this;
}
```

`my_type` is `uint32_t` and `target_type` is `uint8_t`. So, `std::is_same<my_type, target_type>::value` is `false`, so `return *this;` won't be executed.

However, it will be **compiled**! And the compiler reports an error, because you definitely can't return `*this` (type `c<uint32_t>`), in a function supposed to return a  `c<uint8_t>`, as they are different types...

Every path of your template function must be valid for compilation, even if some of it is protected against runtime execution...

Comment: I've been bitten by this one numerous times. [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) has been my go-to solution, though there may be neater ones.

Comment: @Rook: I did not mention that because I'm not sure how this would help for this specific issue.

Comment: You can take the brute-force of duplicating the entire function, with one version enabled for the special case, etc. That should work, I think.

Comment: @Rook: If you think it may help, I can make this answer a "community wiki" then you can update it.

Comment: Looks like someone else has already made an answer with that fix in it, so you may as well leave yours as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In this case what you'll need are two versions of the function, one for the same type and the other for the other types. One possibility:

```
template<typename target_type>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<my_type, target_type>::value, c<target_type> >::type
convert() {
    return *this;
}

template<typename target_type>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<my_type, target_type>::value, c<target_type> >::type
convert() {
    int target_size = sizeof(((c<target_type>*)0)->x);
    int my_size = sizeof(x);

    if (my_size < target_size) {
        return c<target_type>(x << (target_size - my_size) * 8);
    }

    my_type rounder = ((x >> (my_size - target_size) * 8 - 1) & 9) > 4;
    return c<target_type>((x >> (my_size - target_size) * 8) + rounder);    
}
```

How this works is that the `std::enable_if` enables the first function in the case the types are the same, and the other function in all the other cases when the types are not the same.